# AWS S3 Transfer acceleration status not alterable

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I need to activate transfert accelerate on one of my buckets in S3, but I can't because of account limitation.

I've tried so far:

- creating a user with IAM, gave him AdministratorAccess, create a bucket, enable transfer accelerate, got this (via the CLI):

```
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutBucketAccelerateConfiguration operation: Access Denied
```

- same thing via the console, same error.
- same thing with the root account ( I guess with the root account I have all the permissions ).

[image: S3 error]

Answer (score 0):

still relevant?
if so, from the official docs:

Add a named profile for the administrator user in the AWS CLI config file. You use this profile when executing the AWS CLI commands.

```
[adminuser] 
aws_access_key_id = adminuser access key ID 
aws_secret_access_key = adminuser secret access key 
region = aws-region
```

does this work for you?
aws s3 ls --profile adminuser